# setColumnRemarks is not supported on mysql

Tags: liquibase

I use liquibase diff generate the diff between dev mysql and prod mysql, I see there exist some change set like:

When I run the diff file, it shows exception like:
setColumnRemarks is not supported on mysql, db/changelog/V1.1.0_prod_uat.xml::1524893614482-984::davy (generated)
setColumnRemarks is not supported on mysql, db/changelog/V1.1.0_prod_uat.xml::1524893614482-985::davy (generated)
setColumnRemarks is not supported on mysql, db/changelog/V1.1.0_prod_uat.xml::1524893614482-986::davy (generated)

```
at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.validate(DatabaseChangeLog.java:276)
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:198)
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179)
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:317)
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:269)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
```

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Object's comment update (Liquibase's `set*Remarks`) is not supported for some databases, including MySQL. So immediate fix could be to remove this action from your change log.

In my project we generating change sets by comparing (with `liquibase diffChangeLog`) 2 schemas, and `setColumnRemarks` actions are included although they cannot be executed afterwards. So I'm just removing these actions from resulting change sets.

I am afraid a proper solution would be to add appropriate MySQL SQL generator implementation to Liquibase.